# What is the name that describes all buttons, fields, dropdowns, etc.?

Tags: buttons, dropdown

There must be a name that describes all the interactive UI components that register data in some manner but unfortunately I can't think of it!

Does anyone know the name that describes all buttons, fields, dropdowns, etc.?

Comment: “Controls” maybe? But unfortunately this question doesn’t follow the rules of this site.

Comment: Generally referred to as 'form elements.'

Comment: @jazZRo oops! sorry, what's wrong with the question?

Comment: You have to be more specific about what 'interactive UI components' mean... because even a label that doesn't allow you to enter information can be interactive if there is a tooltip feature for it.

Comment: @MichaelLai is right. But also there isn’t one true answer, everyone can have a different name for it and it would be correct. I also don’t find it related to UX enough.

Comment: @jazzRo have updated the question to be more specific

Comment: The question is a tad off topic, but I do find the way to classify components an interesting debate. I noticed everyone has their own way of working. I usually label my toggles, radios and checkboxes as "form / controls / item" and buttons as their own category in, for example, "button / primary / hover".  But, this is in the end all workflow related so there's no 'wrong' way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Form components**

These cover

- button
- input
- text/label
- textarea
- radio
- checkbox
- slider/range
- dropdown
- accordion
- progress bars

List is not exhaustive, but should give you an idea of what category Form elements comprises of.

Logic being they are mostly the elements which enable form interactions.